# Error que no encuentro en un bucle while con contador

Tags: php

llevo dándole vueltas a este código por un buen rato, y no consigo encontrar el error. Si alguien me puede ayudar estaré muy agradecida.

El problema es que el contador no se autosuma. He probado con $c++ y no se sumaba, así que lo he tenido que cambiar por $c=$c+1, que es lo mismo, y este si me funciona. Pero a pesar de todo sigue sin funcionar, porque a la siguiente vuelta vuelve a ser el valor del contador 0.

```
// Si el string $month Y el string $year no estan vacios    
if(!empty($month) && !empty($year)){

       $c=0;
       //Buscalos dos strings en la array $dates
       while( !in_array( strtolower($exists), $dates) ): ?>

         //Si no estan en la array imprime por pantalla la etiqueta option con los valores de los string $year y $month 
         <option value="<?= $month ?>-<?= $year ?>"><?= $month ?> <?= $year ?></option>

         //Añademe en un solo string las variables $year y $string a la array dates para poder seguir comparando y buscando en las siguientes iteraciones. Ya que todo este bloque esta dentro de un while     
         <?php $dates[$c]= strtolower($month.' '.$year); 

         $c=$c+1;

        endwhile; 

     } ?>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78145/discussion-on-question-by-pip-error-que-no-encuentro-en-un-bucle-while-con-conta).